# file_put_contents doesn't work with json laravel & php

Tags: php, json, laravel, file-put-contents

I tried everything to push item into `json` file but when call
`file_put_contents("file.json",$data)` doesn't work and the page shutdown.

Here's my controller code.

```
public function addJson()
{
    $titulo = Input::get('title');
    $name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

    $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("js/data.json"), true);
    array_push($arr['galerias'], array('id' => count($arr['galerias'])+1, 'name' => $name, 'img' => 'galeria/'.$name));
    $arr2 = $arr['galerias'];
    $arr = json_encode($arr);
    echo $arr;
    file_put_contents('js/data.json', $arr);
    return view('main.prueba')->with('name',$arr2);
}
```

And here is the `json` file.

```
{
 "galerias": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Fiesta Privada",
  "img": "galeria/FP.JPG"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Fiesta Privada",
  "img": "galeria/FP2.JPG"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Fiesta Privada",
  "img": "galeria/FP3.JPG"
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Fiesta Privada",
  "img": "galeria/FP4.JPG"
},
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "Fiesta Privada",
  "img": "galeria/FP5.JPG"
},
{
  "id": 6,
  "name": "Fiesta Privada",
  "img": "galeria/FP6.JPG"
},
{
  "id": 7,
  "name": "Los Kjarkas",
  "img": "galeria/Los_Kjarkas.jpg"
},
{
  "id": 8,
  "name": "Palmenia Pizarro",
  "img": "galeria/Palmenia_Pizarro.jpg"
},
{
  "id": 9,
  "name": "Palmenia Pizarro",
  "img": "galeria/Palmenia_Pizarro_2.jpg"
},
{
  "id": 10,
  "name": "Palmenia Pizarro",
  "img": "galeria/Palmenia_Pizarro_3.jpg"
}
]
}
```

Heeeelp me pls :C

Comment: have you check 777 permissions and Apache permissions

Comment: $temp = file_put_contents('js/data.json', $arr); and echo $temp. and see it returns true or false;

Comment: yes, last night think about it, permission problem. ty C:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It could be a permission problem**

Is the directory `/js` chmoded to 777? sometimes php won't allow you to access directories if they don't have enough permission. I don't know about blank errors though.

Try to see if it has enough permissions, if not, then set it to 777 and try it.